# How do i read the RGB values of an image in Verilog from a hex file generated in Matlab for processing?

Tags: verilog, matlab, modelsim

I have used Matlab to generate hex file for an image (1200 * 900 resolution). The hex file is like [image]

There are such 3240000 rows. How do i read this in verilog to performing some processing (filtering out areas where R,G,B values are in some desired range) and then write it into text so that Matlab could return how the image looks like after processing.
Any lead on such image processing is much appreciated.

Comment: What is one pixel's depth? (8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit etc)

Comment: And why do you want Verilog to do this, while a MATLAB script can do the same

Comment: 8 bits each for R,G,B. Trying a simulation now for an FPGA based implementation in the end

Comment: What are you trying to implement on FPGA. The end objective?

Comment: Skin detection from the image

Comment: No. I mean what's the functionality of the FPGA design? What is the input, what's the output?

Comment: I am trying to read the image file converted using Matlab as hex values in modelsim and then apply filtering criteria to categorise as skin and then output the processed image as either a bmp or a text file that could be converted to image again using Matlab.

Comment: Okay so you want this only in simulation or make it work on FPGA board?

Comment: Because in my knowledge, reading a file from PC using FPGA and dumping the output into a file in your PC is not a straight forward process at all. Its easy in simulation though. File handling functions are not synthesisable in hardware.

Comment: I am only trying simulation now being a beginner

Comment: Then isn't it simple? You know what each of these values signify in each line right? Read the value line by line, process the pixel, write to a new file.

Comment: Synchronisation or delay in adjacent pixels to be considered? Could you suggest any reads on such image processing exercises as i am a beginner to it?

Comment: Do you understand this hex file and what each value means?

Comment: Not fully to be honest..as the R G B values are listed line by line. So there has to be a sync among these values while reading at a particular pixel right?

Answer (score 1):

The image is of resolution 1200x900. It means it contains 1080000 pixels. Each pixel is represented by 24-bit RGB data in the hex file generated by MATLAB. 8 bits to represent intensities of R, G and B components in each pixel. So each line represents R/G/B component. Three lines represent a pixel, so total of 3240000 lines represent the complete image.

If you want to process this image in Verilog, for example manipulate brightness/change hue of pixels etc, you simply have to change R/G/B values of each pixel. For eg: if you increase the RGB value uniformly, the pixel becomes brighter, decrease to make the pixel darker. Increase R/G to make the pixel warmer, increase G/B make the pixel cooler. etc

What you need to do is write a Verilog code to read line by line from the file in hex format, update the R/G/B values as per how you need to process that pixel (there must be image processing algorithms based on what kind of processing you need to do to the pixels), and write the new hex value of R/G/B to a new file. You have the "processed image" in new hex file finally. Give that to MATLAB.

Comment: Could you help with code sample on how each pixel information could be reconstructed with the hex file generated from matlab having R, G, B values line by line?

Comment: Its not in the policy of ESE, to give codes unless there's specificity. You can find samples in Google on how to do file read and file write operations with Verilog.